# If $\det(A+B)$ and $\det(A)$ are real numbers, must $\det(B)$ be real?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

Is this true for any two matrices of complex numbers, and if not, what counterexamples are there? If one of these was a matrix of real numbers, would this property hold?

I've been playing around with this, but since I can't find a way to write $\det(A+B)$ in terms of $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$. I haven't made much progress.

Comment: Regarding writing $\det(A+B)$ in terms of $\det(A),\det(B)$: linear algebra is not my strongest suit, but I believe that this is in general impossible. Certain approximations can be very useful, however, if the appropriate norm of one matrix is small with respect to the other.

Comment: @Kriesler, it is considered poor form on this website to delete or clear your question after you receive an answer. If you're satisfied with the answer provided, you can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Consider $A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ i&0}$ for instance.